# Showing ${\ell}_{p_1} \cap {\ell}_{p_2} \subset {\ell}_{\lambda p_1 + (1-\lambda) p_2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

**Question:** Given $(1 \leq p_{1}<p_{2}<\infty)$ and $p=\lambda p_{1}+(1-\lambda) p_{2}$ for some $\lambda$ with $(0<\lambda<1)$ .

**a.** Show that if $x \in l^{p_{1}} \cap l^{p_{2}}$ then
$$
\|x\|_{p} \leq\|x\|_{p_{1}}^{\lambda}\|x\|_{p_{2}}^{1-\lambda}
$$
and hence $l^{p_{1}} \cap l^{p_{2}} \subset l^{p}.$

**b.** Show a similar inequality when we have $p_{2}=\infty$.

---

My attempt so far:

Since I'm asked to show the following at the end
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{p}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{\lambda p_{1}+(1-\lambda)_{p_{2}}} \leq\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{p_{1}}\right)^{\frac{\lambda}{p_{1}}} \cdot\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{p_{2}}\right)^{\frac{1-\lambda}{p_{2}}}
$$
I thought of using Hölder's Inequality ( $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{j} y_{j}\right| \leq\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{j}\right|^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left|y_{j}\right|^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$, where $1/p+1/q=1$
for sequence spaces.
So, I had to obtain some inequality of the form:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{\lambda p_{1}+(1-\lambda) p_{2}} \leqslant\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{\lambda p_{1}a}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{(1-\lambda) p_{2} b} \right)^{\frac{1}{b}},
$$
where $1/a+1/b=1$.
So I set
$$\lambda_{p_{1}} a=p_{1} \Rightarrow a=\frac{p_{1}}{\lambda p_{1}} \\
(1-\lambda) p_{2} b=p_{2} \Rightarrow b=\frac{p_{2}}{(1-\lambda) p_{2}}$$
Clearly, $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=1$ but $\frac{1}{a} \neq \frac{p_{1}}{\lambda}$, and $\frac{1}{b} \neq \frac{p_{2}}{1- \lambda}$

Am I doing something wrong? Or there is something missing in the question? I am open to any help. And I would be glad to get any hint regarding the part $b$.